# Is it possible to create my own Salesforce Trailhead Module?

Tags: trailhead

I'm curious to know if it's possible to create my own Trailhead Module and have it published on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home).

It would contain learning material, in a question and answer format, for my app on the AppExchange.

Does anyone know if this something Salesforce facilitates or even allows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be able to use [`MyTrailhead`](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/mytrailhead) for this sort of thing. Not sure if it is yet Generally Available or how much it will cost.

Comment: That was what came to my mind as well.

Comment: I think its important to note the difference between both platforms, 1 Trailhead being available to the public through https://trailhead.salesforce.com/ and the other to your company Org and will only be available to the public in the 2nd half of 2018. as per the FAQ

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible to do this for displaying content via the trailhead site.

Its important to note the difference between both platforms, 1 Trailhead being available to the public through trailhead.salesforce.com and the other to your company Org and will only be available to the public in the 2nd half of 2018. as per the [FAQ](https://quip.com/IthKAuemOn5O).

The FAQ mentions this key difference:

No one will have access to your trailheads except for employees (at launch at least, users with a standard salesforce license, this is subject to change in the future).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if they will fit ISVs into that picture. Hard to imagine they wouldn't.

Comment: not in the short term as far as i am concerned, we have had conversations with the trailhead team and it is not in their roadmap any time soon (maybe this will change in a year or so)